# Example of techan.js using ISO 8061 date format with hours

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, iso, techan.js

Does anyone have an example of a TechanJS H1, hourly chart (http://techanjs.org/) that uses the ISO 8061 date standard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: 
Use the following techan formats:

```
// JavaScript
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse,
      timeFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
      valueFormat = d3.format(',.5fs');
```

Use the following date format (note exactly ISO but it's what C# Json WebAPI's outputting which is what I'm after):

```
// C#
DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
// 2015-08-24T17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look into test/spec/bundle/_util/date.js (v.0.6.0-6)
there should be a function called parseIso8601.

I wrote it myself :)